# How can I print a list of data each in its own label underneath each other

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a large list of data that I want to display on my app, but I having trouble finding a way to print the data in a vertical matter, each list element in its own label underneath the last. In the future I wish to replace the labels with `MDCard`.

Also if the list reaches the bottom of the screen, how will I be able to scroll down?

*.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        list1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']

        for x in list1:
            self.add_widget(Label(text=x,pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}))


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('NearMe.kv')

class NearMeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NearMeApp().run()
```

*.kv

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:

<FirstWindow>:
    name:"FirstWindow"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__()` method of `FirstWindow` is adding all the `Labels` to the `FirstWindow`, but they are all at the same position. I suspect that you actually want to add the `Labels` to the innermost `GridLayout`. To do that, you can add an `id` to that `GridLayout` in the `kv`:

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:

<FirstWindow>:
    name:"FirstWindow"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            id: grid  # Added id
            cols:3
```

Then refactor your `FirstWindow` class to use that `id`:

```
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.fill)  # this must be delayed until the `id` is available

    def fill(self, dt):
        grid = self.ids.grid  # get a reference to the GridLayout

        list1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']

        for x in list1:
            grid.add_widget(Label(text=x,pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}))  # add Labels to the GridLayout
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, could you explain the clock part?

Comment: The `Clock.schedule_once()` is used to delay the call to `fill()` because the `ids` in a class are not yet available in the `__init__()` method.